# Install function using shell script in MongoDB

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

I have a Virtual Machine (CentOS) with an entirely scripted environment including a MongoDB. I have a requirement for an auto incrementing id column on my collection and have followed instructions from the mongoDB documentation to use a counters collection and a function to update that collection.

Full details can be found here :http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

I can get this working in the mongo shell so my inserts call the function and increment the sequence and I'm now looking to script it as part of the VM provisioning but I'm not sure how to deal with the function part.

I have created the counters collection in my bash script using:

```
mongo audit --eval "db.counters.insert({_id: 'sequence',seq: 0})"
```

Next I add my function to the system.js collection:

```
mongo audit --eval "db.getCollection('system.js').save({_id:'getNextSequence', value:'function getNextSequence(name) { var ret = db.counters.findAndModify( { query: { _id: name }, update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, new: true }); return ret.seq; }'})"
```

Now I try to load the saved script:

```
mongo audit --eval "db.loadServerScripts()"
```

This gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is their another way to install a function which I can call on every insert to my collection?

My inserts will be executed from some JRuby code running in a Sinatra webservice and looks similar to this:

```
db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("sequence"),
     name: "Bob Builder."
   }
)
```

Thanks for any help.

As requested this is the script I use to start mongo and create collections as part of my VM provisioning:

```
#start mongo service
sudo service mongod start

#set config to restart service on reboot
sudo chkconfig mongod on

#create DB collections and indexes
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('audit').errors.ensureIndex({title_number:1})"
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('audit').minteds.ensureIndex({title_number:1})"
```

This has been working fine so far but now I need an auto incrementing id.

I've followed the instructions on the above link and added the function manually through the interactive shell and called the function on my insert as shown on the users collection above. At this point I started looking at scripting what I had done and have managed to create the counters collection which will hold the sequence count

```
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('audit').counters.insert({_id: 'sequence',seq: 0})"
```

I then tried (but probably wrongly judging by your reply) installing function to the server using

```
mongo audit --eval "db.getCollection('system.js').insert({_id:'getNextSequence', value:'function getNextSequence(name) { var ret = db.counters.findAndModify( { query: { _id: name }, update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, new: true }); return ret.seq; }'})"
```

Using Robomongo I could see the function was there but it didn't seem to work when I tried an insert. Basically I need to script the process shown in the link above but am unable to get the function installed/running without doing it manually. I guess I'm missing something fundamental but I can't see what it is so your comments are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to install a function that runs on every insert into the server. If you need such a function, you need to call it at every insert in your code. There's some typo or something in your javascript that's causing the unexpected token error, but it's irrelevant because you don't want to proceed with your current method.

To setup the autoincrement, define a `getNextSequence` function in the JRuby code and then call it for each insert. Any other client doing inserts will also need a `getNextSequence` function to call before inserts/upserts as well. You cannot setup a function to run for every insert on the server-side; *every client* must take care to use a `getNextSequence` function to perform a proper insertion and maintain the autoincrementing `_id`.

Comment: I'll amend my question to show details of my provisioning.